# Assign C# string to Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, string-conversion

```
 var nUserID = '<% if (ids != null) {ids.userID.ToString();}%>'
```

Note: ids is not null nor ids.userID is null but em getting nUserID = ""
Is there any way to convert C# string to Javascript string?

Comment: You should not think of this as "converting a C# string to a Javascript string". Such a thing does not make sense .. the two never interact in this scenario where the page is being rendered. Your C# is merely being interpreted and the result dumped into the HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For write it direct on page you need to use the `Response.Write` as

```
 var nUserID = <% if (ids != null) {Response.Write(ids.userID.ToString());}%>
```

beside that, if you need to add at the end `;` or place it inside quotas is up to you.

The `<% %>` did not write on page, just run the code.
The `<%= %>` write on the page as the  `Response.Write`

Comment: ...or just have it evaluated for you with: `var nUserID = "<%= ids.userID %>"`

Comment: @SimonWhitehead But if the user need some check for null ?

Comment: Touche - I completely disregarded that part. My apologies. I would still use `<%= %>` but wrap the NullRef check in a method :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var nUserID = '<%=((ids != null) ? ids.userID.ToString() : "0")%>';
```

Answer (score 0):

More appropriate solution would be to to save your `ids.userID` to data attribute of some related html element or just create invisible `div` element with all C# data you want to use in your javascript code as `data` attributes. And then use jQuery to extract that data in scripts.

```
<div id="settings" style="display: none;" data-user-id="<%= ids.userID %>"></div>
```

and javascript:

```
var nUserID = $('#settings').data('user-id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Something Like this:

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">

   var nUserID = '<%=ids.userID.ToString()%>';

if(!nUserID)
{ 
 //check for null in javascript
alert(nUserID);

}

   </script>
```